# Calculating Arc Hyperbolic CoTangent faster than using a standard power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I have used the standard Power-Series to calculate Arc Hyperbolic Co-Tangent trig function. But as with my other posts before, it is very slow. 
Here is the standard Power-Series, taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Series_expansions

$$ \operatorname{arcoth} x = \operatorname{artanh} \frac1x  = x^{-1} + \frac {x^{-3}} {3} + \frac {x^{-5}} {5} + \frac {x^{-7}} {7} +\frac {x^{-9}} {9} + \frac {x^{-11}} {11} + \frac {x^{-13}} {13} \cdots \\
                       = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {x^{-(2n+1)}} {2n+1} , \qquad \left| x \right| > 1 $$

I have used a different form to speed it up, which it did not.
$$ \operatorname{arcoth} x = \frac {1}{x} + \left ( \frac{1}{3}*\frac{1}{x^{3}} \right ) + \left ( \frac{1}{5}*\frac{1}{x^{5}} \right ) + \left ( \frac{1}{7}*\frac{1}{x^{7}} \right ) \\ + \left ( \frac{1}{9}*\frac{1}{x^{9}} \right ) + \left ( \frac{1}{11}*\frac{1}{x^{11}} \right ) + \left ( \frac{1}{13}*\frac{1}{x^{13}} \right )+\cdots   $$

But it is easier to reproduce in my calculator program. The part that is taking so long are terms $$ \left ( \frac{1}{x^{7}} \right ) $$ and higher. The time spent dividing  $$ {x^{7}} $$ into $$ {1} $$ is huge. At this iteration, it takes about 15 seconds. The next ones just keep growing, using more time. My question is , Is there another way? Another Power Series? Redefine or rewrite $$ \left ( \frac{1}{7}*\frac{1}{x^{7}} \right ) $$  ?  Any suggestions are welcomed. Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: If you calculate $y := x^{-1}$ just once, then the series becomes a power series in $y$. Then you can rewrite the series in [Horner-like form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method).

Comment: Please explain this a little more, with an example or a procedure. I do not know the Horner-like form. Thank you.

Comment: The Horner-like form is essentially the same form described in your other questions. (The Wikipedia entry explains it in detail.) In this case (with $y=1/x$), you'd have $$y\left(\frac11 + y^2 \left( \frac13 + y^2 \left(\frac15 +  \cdots \right.\right.\right.$$

Comment: So use y = (1/x), then the form you gave?!

Comment: I think that's what I wrote, isn't it? :)

Comment: Ok, I will try it, Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At each iteration I suggest that you compute the new values for $a_{n+1}=a_{n}*yy$ and $b_{n+1}=b_{n}+2$, with $a_1=1/x$, $b_1=1$ and $yy = 1/(x*x)$, following the suggestion by [Blue](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/409/blue). Then the new sum is $s_{n+1} = s_{n}+a_{n+1}/b_{n+1}$.

The code could be something like:

```
a = 1/x;
b = 1;
yy = a * a;

s = a;

j = 1;
max_iterations = 7;

while(j < max_iterations)
{
    j = j + 1;
    a = a * yy;
    b = b + 2;
    s = s + a/b;
}
```

In general, the sums are faster than the products, which in turn are faster than the quotients and the powers.

Comment: Hey, It worked really fast. Thanks Ertxiem and Blue

Comment: You may try to (slowly) increase $max_iterations$ to a higher value than $7$. If you think it's appropriate, you can accept my answer (there is a green button).

Comment: I meant max_iterations. :)

Comment: Ertxiem, Would you mind turning your code into a Horner like-form. I am trying to do it but I fail at it. This is for my final documentation that I want to put into Math.stackexchange.com

Comment: Do you mean something like: $$ x^{-1}(1 + x^{-2}(\frac{1}{3} + x^{-2}(\frac{1}{5} + x^{-2}(\frac{1}{7} + x^{-2}(\frac{1}{9} + x^{-2}(\frac{1}{11} + \ldots)))))) \ ? $$ I.e.: `s = a + (1 + yy*(1/3 + yy*(1/5 + yy*(1/7 + yy*(1/9 + yy*(1/11 + ...))))));`

Comment: Yes, Thank you very much