# Calculating Arc Hyperbolic CoSecant faster than using a standard power series

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, power-series, trigonometric-series

I have used the standard Power-Series to calculate Arc Hyperbolic Co-Secant trig function. But as with my other posts before, it is very slow. Here is the standard Power-Series, taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_hyperbolic_functions#Series_expansions

$$ \operatorname{arcsch} x = \operatorname{arsinh} \frac1x  = x^{-1} - \left( \frac {1} {2} \right) \frac {x^{-3}} {3} + \left( \frac {1 \cdot 3} {2 \cdot 4} \right)  \frac {x^{-5}} {5}  - \left( \frac {1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5} {2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6} \right)  \frac {x^{-7}} {7} \pm\cdots \\
                      = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac {(-1)^n(2n)!} {2^{2n}(n!)^2} \right) \frac {x^{-(2n+1)}} {2n+1} , \qquad \left| x \right| > 1 $$
I have used a different form to speed it up, which it did not.
$$ \operatorname{arcsch} x = \frac {1}{x} - \left( \frac {1} {2} \right) \frac {1} {3 x^{3}}+ \left( \frac {1 \cdot 3} {2 \cdot 4} \right)  \frac{1} {5x^{5}}  - \left( \frac {1 \cdot 3 \cdot 5} {2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6} \right)  \frac {1} {7x^{7}} \pm\cdots \\ 
                      = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \frac {(-1)^n(2n)!} {2^{2n}(n!)^2} \right) \frac {x^{-(2n+1)}} {2n+1} , \qquad \left| x \right| > 1 $$
But it is easier to reproduce in my calculator program. The part that is taking so long are terms
$$ \left ( \frac {1} {7x^{7}} \right ) $$
and higher. The time spent dividing  $$  {7x^{7}} $$ into $$ 1 $$  is huge. At this iteration, it takes about 15 seconds. The next ones just keep growing, using more time.

And yes, this post is just my last post [Calculating Arc Hyperbolic CoTangent faster than using a standard power series](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3170079/calculating-arc-hyperbolic-cotangent-faster-than-using-a-standard-power-series). Here, 2 persons showed me the Horner's method and a programming procedure. It was really fast, compared to what I was using before.

I am hoping that there is a Horner-like form that a person, you people, can show me. I have read the Wiki page that explains the Horner's method, but that does not mean I can create the method.

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: Have you looked at _where_ the Horner-style form in the previous answer came from? Have you tried recreating it, and if so, where are you stuck?

Comment: Ertxiem gave me the programming code and Blue gave me the Horner-like form. From my point-of-view (POV), Both of them helped. But they did tell me where they got it from. And when I look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horner%27s_method , it is beyond my skill level. OK?

Comment: ## But they did NOT tell me. But thanks anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fundamentally, Horner form involves nothing more than convenient parenthesization and factoring to avoid re-powering the variable with each term. For instance,
$$\begin{align}
a_0 + a_1 z + a_2 z^2 + a_3 z^3 + a_4 z^4 &\quad\to\quad 
a_0 + z\left(a_1 + a_2 z + a_3 z^2  + a_4 z^3 \right) \\
&\quad\to\quad
a_0 + z\left(a_1 + z \left( a_2 + a_3 z + a_4 z^2 \right)\; \right) \\
&\quad\to\quad
a_0 + z\left(a_1 + z \left( a_2 + z \left( a_3 + a_4 z \right)\; \right)\; \right) \\
\end{align} \tag{1}$$

That's all there is to it, really, although sometimes (especially with power series) we can exploit the specific nature of the coefficients.

So, a first pass at the hyperbolic arccosecant series would look like this (in stages):

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{arcsch}(x) &= x^{-1}\left(\;1 
- \frac12\cdot\frac13 x^{-2}
+ \frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\cdot \frac15 x^{-4}
- \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\cdot\frac17 x^{-6} 
+ \cdots \right. \tag{2a}\\[4pt]
&= x^{-1}\left(\;1 
+ x^{-2}\left(- \frac12\cdot\frac13
+ \frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\cdot \frac15 x^{-2}
- \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\cdot\frac17 x^{-4} 
+ \cdots \right.\right. \tag{2b}\\[4pt]
&= x^{-1}\left(\;1 
+ x^{-2}\left(- \frac12\cdot\frac13
+ x^{-2}\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\cdot \frac15
- \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\cdot\frac17 x^{-2} 
+ \cdots \right.\right.\right. \tag{2c}\\[4pt]
&= x^{-1}\left(\;1 
+ x^{-2}\left(- \frac12\cdot\frac13
+ x^{-2}\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\cdot \frac15
+ x^{-2}\left(- \frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\cdot\frac17 
+ \cdots \right.\right.\right.\right. \tag{2d}
\end{align}$$

All I did was add parentheses and pull out powers of $x$ as I went along. I made no changes to coefficients.

We can clean this up a little, though. First, define $y := 1/x$ and $z:=1/x^2$ (which you can compute once and store), so that we have

$$\operatorname{arcsch}(x) = y\left(\;1 
+ z\left(-\frac12\cdot\frac13
+ z\left(\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\cdot \frac15 
+ z\left(-\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5}{2\cdot 4\cdot 6}\cdot\frac17 
+ \cdots\right.\right.\right.\right. \tag{3}$$

Now, notice that the coefficients are accumulating factors. We can avoid re-calculating them by factoring-out at appropriate levels. Again doing this in stages ...

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{arcsch}(x) &= y\left(\;1 
+ z\cdot \frac12 \left(-\frac13
+ z\left(\frac{3}{4}\cdot \frac15 
- z\left(\frac{3\cdot 5}{4\cdot 6}\cdot\frac17 
+ \cdots\right.\right.\right.\right. \tag{4a} \\[4pt]
&= y\left(\;1 
+ z\cdot \frac12 \left(-\frac13
+ z\cdot \frac34 \left(\frac15 
+ z\left(-\frac56\cdot\frac17 
+ \cdots\right.\right.\right.\right. \tag{4b} \\[4pt]
&= y\left(\;1 
+ z\cdot \frac12 \left(-\frac13
+ z\cdot \frac34 \left(\frac15 
+ z\cdot \frac56 \left(-\frac17 
+ \cdots\right.\right.\right.\right. \tag{4c}
\end{align}$$

We can even factor-out negatives as we go, to get

$$\begin{align}
\operatorname{arcsch}(x) &= y\left(\;1 
- z\cdot \frac12 \left(\frac13
- z\cdot \frac34 \left(\frac15 
- z\cdot \frac56 \left(\frac17 
- \cdots\right.\right.\right.\right. \tag{5}
\end{align}$$

I'll leave it to OP to implement the corresponding programmatic computational algorithm.

In any case, conversion to Horner form is entirely mechanical, at least at the first-pass level. Optimizing for factorable coefficients is relatively straightforward, as well, although it isn't always possible. (Factorials and double-factorials are well-suited to this.) For practice, OP can revisit his past fast-calculation questions, convert each series to Horner-form on his own, and then compare to answers and/or comments he's received. And, of course, he should be able to apply this procedure to new series, too.

Comment: Good God, This should be published! Thank you much